# infinite api calls within few seconds Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Home` component in which I call an api, get the data and store in in a state. And finally display the data in an arranged way. Here is the code

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
//import context
import MainContext from "../context/MainContext";
//api
import { homeDataURL, topSearchesURL } from "../api/base";
import { getResponse } from "../api";

const Home = () => {
  const { topSearches, setTopSearches } = useContext(MainContext);
  getResponse(
     topSearchesURL(),
       (data) => {
         setTopSearches(data);
       },
       (err) => alert(err)
  );  
  return <div></div>;
};

export default Home;
```

And the `getResponse()` function

```
export const getResponse = (url, callback, errcallback) => {
  axios
    .get(url)
    .then((data) => {
      if (callback != null) {
        callback(data.data);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (errcallback != null) {
        errcallback(err);
      }
    });
};
```

But this function goes to an infinite loop with numerous api hits, i want this to run just one time when the `Home` component loads.

There is a React hook `useEffect` which needs a dependecy array, leaving it blank like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    getResponse(
        topSearchesURL(),
        (data) => {
          setTopSearches(data);
          console.log(data)
        },
        (err) => alert(err)
      );
  }, [])
```

gives a warning `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setTopSearches'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`  Removing the array dependency is not an option, so what should I do? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: `axios` returns a promise. Why are you using callbacks in that function?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning Axios promise, and also no need to use callback use async/await.

```
export const getResponse = (url) => axios.get(url).then((data) => data.data);

// Component
const apiUrl = topSearchesURL();
useEffect(() => {
  const run = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await getResponse(apiUrl);
      setTopSearches(data);
    } catch (error) {
      alert("Something went wrong");
    }
  };
  run();
}, [apiUrl]);
```